# Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline failed with exit code 1

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, cicd

Trying to get my Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline to push a bunch of images to Azure Container Registry, although it continues to fail

```
The process 'C:\Windows\system32\docker.exe failed with exit code 1
```

[DockerCompose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZrR9.png)

[Pipeline result error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG1R1.png)

[Error analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unJS1.png)

YAML

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - Initial-K8-Setup

resources:
- repo: self
  clean: true


# define variables
variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'HAWeb2-CFS-NonProd'
  # Container Registry Type
  crType: 'Azure Container Registry'
  # Container Name
  AZURE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY: 'crschacfsnonprod' #.azurecr.io'
  dockerComposeFileArgs: 'REGISTRY=crschacfsnonprod.azurecr.io/'
  dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
  # Additional Docker File
  addDockerComposeFiles: 'docker-compose.override.yml'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '7739b21f-2572-4f36-ab8b-df15ab821756'
  imageName: aquarium
  imageTag: demo
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'windows-2019'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:

    # Log into ACR Registry
    - script: |
        docker login crschacfsnonprod.azurecr.io/ -u $(acrUsername) -p $(acrPassword2)
      env:
        acrLoginServer: crschacfsnonprod.azurecr.io
        acrUsername: $(acrUsername)
        acrPassword: $(acrPassword2)
      displayName: 'Docker login to ACR'

    # Build Images
    - task: DockerCompose@0
      inputs:
        containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
        azureSubscription: 'HAWeb2-CFS-NonProd'
        azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"crschacfsnonprod.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/5e2acfcb-7aeb-443d-9ea4-bc7553a51276/resourceGroups/rg-ha-cfs-nonprod-001/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/crschacfsnonprod"}'
        dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
        additionalDockerComposeFiles: 'docker-compose.override.yml'
        dockerComposeFileArgs: 'REGISTRY=crschacfsnonprod.azurecr.io/'
        action: 'Build services'
        additionalImageTags: '$(Build.BuildNumber)-$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
        includeLatestTag: true

    # Push Images
    - task: DockerCompose@0
      inputs:
        containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
        azureSubscription: 'HAWeb2-CFS-NonProd'
        azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"crschacfsnonprod.azurecr.io", "id" : "/subscriptions/5e2acfcb-7aeb-443d-9ea4-bc7553a51276/resourceGroups/rg-ha-cfs-nonprod-001/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/crschacfsnonprod"}'
        dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
        additionalDockerComposeFiles: 'docker-compose.override.yml'
        dockerComposeFileArgs: 'REGISTRY=crschacfsnonprod.azurecr.io/'
        action: 'Push services'
        additionalImageTags: '$(Build.BuildNumber)-$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
        includeLatestTag: true

    # Copy Files
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: 'k8s'
        Contents: '**'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/k8s'

    # Publish Artifact
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        artifact: 'Sitecore-Aquarium-XM1'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

[Configured a Docker Registry Service Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evHVA.png)

Azure Container Registry
SKU: Premium
Admin User: Enabled
Identity

- System assigned: Off
- User Assigned: None
  Networking:
- Public network access: All networks

[Now I am unsure how the above Pipeline actually ads up... When looking into Repositories within the ACR, something have actually been pushed, although why does the Pipeline fail?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TylSq.png)

What am I doing wrong?
Can anyone clarify what I might have to do, to resolve this?

Comment: Where are the values for variables `acrUsername` and `acrPassword2` configured?

Comment: As Pipeline variables, Username as String and Password as SecureString

Comment: In your login script, try this instead - `docker login crschacfsnonprod.azurecr.io/ -u $acrUsername -p $acrPassword`